# Auto collapse sidebar menu list when lost focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I just want to ask :

1. how to make the dropdown-menu collpase when the dropdown menu is active?
2. When the mouse hovers to the sidebar, the active dropdown menu expanded again?

i think i just wondering using hover but it doesnt work when i try it, so i hope someone can help me to solve this?

Simple Concept  I Just want :

1. Mouse:hover to sidebar-icon/burger is clicked => sidebar-expanded => menu list that have:submenu clicked => dropdown-menu displayed => mouseOut from sidebar => icon is-collapsed
2. Mouse:hover to sidebar-icon again / sidebar:state(active) => dropdown menu is already expanded

well i dont know that you can understand my question or something.. but i hope u can make this auto collapse menu

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Sidebar links
  $('.sidebar .side-list li a').on('click', function() {
    const $this = $(this);

    if ($this.parent().hasClass('buka')) {
      $this
        .parent()
        .children('.dropdown-menu')
        .slideUp(200, () => {
          $this.parent().removeClass('buka');
        });
    } else {

      $this
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .children('li.buka')
        .children('.dropdown-menu')
        .slideUp(200);

      $this
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .children('li.buka')
        .children('a')
        .removeClass('buka');

      $this
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .children('li.buka')
        .removeClass('buka');

      $this
        .parent()
        .children('.dropdown-menu')
        .slideDown(200, () => {
          $this.parent().addClass('buka');
        });
    }
  });

  // ٍSidebar Toggle
  $('.burger').on('click', e => {
    $('.konten').toggleClass('k-kebuka');
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('s-kebuka');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar bg-cerah">
  <div class="sidebar-dalem">
    <div class="side-konten">
      <ul class="side-list">
        <li class="side-item dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="side-ikon">ICON</span>
            <span class="side-judul">MENU</span>
            <span class="panah">[>]</span>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">SUBMENU #1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">SUBMENU #2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="side-item dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="side-ikon">[X]</span>
            <span class="side-judul">MENU #2</span>
            <span class="panah">[>] ></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">SUBMENU #1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">SUBMENU #2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="side-item">
          <a class="side-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="side-ikon">[X]</span>
            <span class="side-judul">MENU #3</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="konten" class="konten">
  <div class="konten-navbar sticky-top">
    <ul class="navbar-kiri">
      <li>
        <a id="burger" href="javascript:void(0)" class="burger">BURGER ICO</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">SEARCH ICO</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your snippet is missing the relevant HTML. Also, just for reference, use `closest()` instead of chained `parent()` calls, and similarly `find()` instead of repeating `children()`

Comment: well, i try edit my snippets again. and i will try your advice by the way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure CSS, .menu:hover definitely works, but you have to build the entire menu inside of the element that has the :hover pseudo class and also either touching or overlapping:

```css
.popup {
position: relative;
}
button {
width: 8em;
height: 40px;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: 8px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 14em;
  min-height: 8em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  list-style: none;
}
.popup:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="popup"><button>Menu</button>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Certainly, you'd need to style everything properly.

I also seem to remember that JQuery has OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave events that work kind of like :hover too.

Comment: hell yea, thanks for the advice, and the problem was solved i remember that i style the idle collapse in media query so that make my main style not worked. so, i just add hovering line in the media query. that fix the problem thanks dude